# How to access what has been selected using mouse pointers inside the cmd window using c++?

Tags: c++, cmd

We can select and copy from the cmd window using the mouse pointer.
Suppose I have a program which fills the window with random text and then I select any text using the mouse(I dont copy it just select it), then store that portion of text in a string. So how to do this in C++?

I have done this for selections made using keyboard. But I dont have any idea how to do the same using the mouse pointer.

Its not using any clipboards since nothing was copied to clipboard, I want to copy from buffer to a variable.

Comment: Maybe [SetConsoleMode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) (look at `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT`)  and [ReadConsoleInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)?

Comment: This might be of interest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368326/c-win32-text-selection-detection-and-fetching-and-modifying-in-another-applica